# wait for the akka actor for processing pending messages before terminating

Tags: java, spring-boot, akka

I have a spring boot application and when i am stopping the spring boot app the akka actors are getting terminated even they have the messages to be processed. i want to change the behaviour and want that even after spring boot app shutdown, if that akka actors have the messages the it should processed and after that it should get terminated, i tried multiple things but didn't got any luck, i tried graceful shutdown of spring boot.

any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use coordinated shutdown (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/coordinated-shutdown.html) for this.

You can terminate the system in a `PreDestroy` callback like:

```
CoordinatedShutdown.get(system)
                   .runAll(CoordinatedShutdown.jvmExitReason())
                   .get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And then you can register your actor as follows:

```
CoordinatedShutdown.get(system())
                    .addCancellableTask(
                            CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceRequestsDone(),
                            "shutdown-actor",
                            () -> {
                                return Patterns.ask(self, new Stop(), Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                                                    .thenApply(msg -> Done.getInstance());
                        });
```

This will postpone the shutdown of the system until a response to Stop has been received

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way out of the box to accomplish this, but you could have your actors use a [custom mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/mailboxes.html) which has a [MessageQueue](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/dispatch/MessageQueue.html) which notifies a global actor whenever the emptiness of the mailbox changes.  That global actor tracks which actors have at least one message in the mailbox.  You then register a coordinated shutdown hook which will basically ask that actor to complete a future when there are no actors with at least one message.

Note that because actors can send arbitrarily many messages to themselves or to other actors in the course of processing a message, there is no guarantee that there ever will be a point where no actors have messages in their respective mailboxes.  You therefore will probably want to have some means of directing your actors to start using a definition of processing which entails sending fewer onward messages; as a consequence this sort of thing must be custom for your application and fit the problem you're trying to solve with the application (and there's no guarantee that such a definition of processing exists).

For this reason, the more Akka-idiomatic thing is to accept that delivery and processing of a message is generally not guaranteed to ever happen.